# Convert special quotes to regular quotes

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am trying to parse html and I have a string which has weird quotes:

```
‘3’
```

How do I convert their character-encoding to the regular `'`?

Comment: just replace them with str_replace or regex

Comment: better use str_replace.......it wil work

Comment: Why would you do that? ‘3’ is correct in English, '3' is not. If there is `‘3’` in HTML markup (as attribute value, presumably), then you should try to identify and fix the origin of this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly taken from [Convert Smart Quotes back to normal](http://snippets.jc21.com/snippets/php/convert-smart-quotes-back-to-normal/):

```
<?php
function convert_smart_quotes($string) {
    //converts smart quotes to normal quotes.
    $search = array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151));
    $replace = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-');
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
?>
```

Found via: ["php convert curly quotes"](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20convert%20curly%20quotes).

Comment: Didn't work for me, but might be my particular use case.